# save data in two table with a form

Tags: php, mysql

There are three buttons button1, button2 and button3 which opens same bootstrap modal with form. Now problem is that if click on button1 then data will be insert in table1 after submitting the form similarly when click on button2 then data insert in table2 and similarly for button3.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: where is your code and please state your problem clearly

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just edit your question and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a hidden input to form and on click button you can change the value of this hidden input and then you can decide which table should be used for storing the data when the form is posted.

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" id="table" name="table" value="first_table">
    <!-- other inputs -->
</form>


<button id="first_table">First</button>
<button id="second_table">Second</button>
<button id="third_table">Third</button>

<script>
    $( "#first_table" ).click(function() {
        $("#table").val("first_table");
    });
    $( "#second_table" ).click(function() {
        $("#table").val("second_table");
    });
    $( "#third_table" ).click(function() {
        $("#table").val("third_table");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: how can you solve a problem that has not even been stated, you must be a genius

Comment: @SamEzedi you do not need to be genius for that ;) He just does not know that how he can implement the workflow. It would be nice to read the needs carefully before criticize ;) Good luck.